# How to display keys from DB in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, key-value

How can I display the keys from MongoDB in HTML page. I do not want to display the values atached to the keys in UI.

I want to show all the keys but I am not aware how many keys are there in one document.

The DB is nested.

```
   School:{
           Student : {
                "CATEGORY": "Section1", 
                "Team"    :'A'
              },
           Teacher : { "Experience" : 3,

              }
   }
```

I want to extract keys Category, Team , Experience

Comment: Does one document contain all of this structure (both `Student` and `Teacher`) or does your database host different kinds of documents?

Comment: this is in a single document

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

```
Object.keys(someCollection.findOne()); //Returns array of strings
```

Example on the following structure:

```
{
  _id : ...,
  foo : ...,
  bar : ...
}
```

Result:

```
[
  '_id',
  'foo',
  'bar'
]
```

Comment: how to do it in nested case

Comment: Without knowing what kind of result you exactly want, I can only suggest reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: I want keys like category,experience..nested keys only in html